# NS3: how to setup RcvBufSize for each TCP session?

Tags: c++, tcp, buffer, ns-3, setsockopt

I have to run two TCP sessions with different RcvBufSize.

I know the following code can setup the RcvBufSize for all TCP sessions.

```
Config::SetDefault("ns3::TcpSocket::RcvBufSize", UintegerValue (1500000));
```

Actually, I'm looking for the function like `setsockopt()`  to setup SO_RCVBUF for each TCP session.

I also tried to downcast `Ptr<Socket>` to `Ptr<TcpSocket>`, but `SetRcvBufSize()` is private function...

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: I also tried to downcast Ptr<Socket> to Ptr<TcpSocket>, but SetRcvBufSize() is private function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `SndBufSize` in my application using `SetAttribute` call. I have a class with the socket pointer member `ns3::Ptr<ns3::Socket> m_pSocket` and to change the send buffer size I do this:

```
// create tcp socket
m_pSocket = ns3::Socket::CreateSocket( GetNode(), ns3::TcpSocketFactory::GetTypeId() );
m_pSocket->SetAttribute("SndBufSize", ns3::UintegerValue(4096000));
```

So in your case you have to call:

```
yourSocket->SetAttribute("RcvBufSize", ns3::UintegerValue(1500000));
```

This way you can set every attribute of [ns3::TcpSocket](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.24/doxygen/classns3_1_1_tcp_socket.html#details).